# XAML/UWP Custom Control - defining repeating patterns at runtime

Tags: .net, xaml, uwp, custom-controls

I‘m actually trying to get a better understand of building complex custom controls in XAML (specifically UWP, but most of the time, differences to WPF seem minor or are easily converted).

While the basic concepts are pretty clear, I‘m struggling to find out how one could produce an Custom Control behaving similar to a ListView or a DataGrid in Terms of repeating ‚subunits‘ - speaking of providing the control some data binding to a collection of some type which then at runtime shows up as many (entries, rows, whatever) as there are in the collection. I simply don‘t get how to achieve this.

My current assumption is that one has to somehow define a routine in the control class (the constructor, setting an observable collection?) that creates the corresponding amount of ‚subunits‘, textboxes for example.

As this is already the point where I‘m stuck, there is no code example I could give that would be different from the standard xaml/class template when creating a custom control. How do you implement such a ‚dynamic placeholder‘ in the theme definition for instance?

I looked into the source code of the Community Toolkit for the DataGrid Control, as this one has to handle such a requirement in an extremely generic way:

https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid/DataGrid/DataGrid.xaml

https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid/DataGrid/DataGrid.cs

But this was overwhelming, could someone point to a good starting place or sum up the pattern for such a task?

Comment: Are you saying you want to display all the items in a collection? If so, you want an ItemsControl with an ItemTemplate. There's a lot of chaff in here though: The part about "returning a UI component" is not clear to me.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yes, I want to display all items in a collection. I edited my question and tried to clarify the returning statement. In a ListView, you bind to some code-behind element - a simple case may be a collection of 20 floats or with 30 object instances that all have a ‚name‘ attribute. The control then shows a list of 20/30 elements. When there are only 3, the UI will have not more than 3 elements in that control. In a DataGrid you may bind to a Collection of Collection, generically a 2D matrix. Concept stays the same.

Comment: OK, use ItemsControl.

Comment: Thanks, I‘ll try experimenting deriving my custom control from this

Comment: Just use it as-is. It already does everything you say you need.

Comment: I‘m aware of the existing controls and how to implement them. I were just curious how to build something like this in a custom control (as all common 3rd party control frameworks do this somehow) and because I didn‘t get it I assume I‘m missing a basic concept.